# how to have a userinput be ".pushed" into an array

Tags: javascript, html

I would like the user to be able to add a url into the box submit it and then it will be in the array and be displayed in order. I would like this to be able to happen as many times as they click submit.

this is where I am but it searches my computer for the url rather than the web.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>images</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="user_input" />
<button onClick="add()">ADD</button>
<img id="light" width="10%">
<button onclick="colourChange()">Click Me To Cycle Through The Colours</button> 
<script>
var x=1
var user = document.getElementById("user_input");
var colour = ["red.gif", "amber1.gif", "green.gif", "amber1.gif"];

document.getElementById("light").src = colour[0];
function add(){
colour.push(user);
}

function colourChange(){
    document.getElementById("light").src = colour[x];
    x += 1;
    if (x == colour.length ) x = 0
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use your browser console to see errors. There is no array `fruits`. Also have to prevent form submit or page will reload

Comment: onsubmit="return false" var newVal = document.getElementById('url').value;
  colour.push(newVal);

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be reset when user reloads the page, you don't need to use a form.

```
<input type="text" id="user_input" />
<button onClick=add()>ADD</button>
```

And your add function

```
function add(){
  var newVal = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
  fruits.push(newVal); //assuming your array is named fruits, I can't see in your code where you have defined it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your add function with

```
var imageInput = document.querySelector("input[name=url]");
function add(evnt){
    evnt.preventDefault();
    colour.push(imageInput.value);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare the array before you try to push it.
`var fruits = [];`
and then in your add function, get the url element and push to the array you declared previously. It's convenient if you give the element an id.
`function add() { fruits.push(document.getElementById('url').value); }`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>images</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="user">
      insert an image URL to add to cycle: <input type="text" id="url" name="url"><br>
      <button onclick="add()">ADD</button>
    </form>
    <img id="light" width="10%">
    <button onclick="colourChange()">Click Me To Cycle Through The Colours</button>

    <script>
    var x = 1;
    var colour = ["red.gif", "amber1.gif", "green.gif", "amber1.gif"];
    var fruits = [];
    document.getElementById("light").src = colour[0];
    var url = document.getElementById('url');

    function add(){
      fruits.push(url.value);
    }

    function colourChange(){
        document.getElementById("light").src = colour[x];
        x += 1;
        if (x == colour.length ) x = 0
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry it is meant to push it into colour array, ive change it to colour.push

Answer (score 0):

Add into from tag `onsubmit="return false"` and see `add()` function which is mentioned in below line.

```js
var x=1
var colour = ["red.gif", "amber1.gif", "green.gif", "amber1.gif"];
document.getElementById("light").src = colour[0];
function add(){    
  var newVal = document.getElementById('url').value;
  colour.push(newVal);
  document.getElementById('url').value = '';;
}
function colourChange(){
  document.getElementById("light").src = colour[x];
  x += 1;
  if (x == colour.length ) x = 0
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>images</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="user" onsubmit="return false">
                insert an image URL to add to cycle: <input type="text" name="url" id="url"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"  onclick="add()">
            </form> 
            <img id="light" width="10%">
            <button onclick="colourChange()">Click Me To Cycle Through The Colours</button> 
            
        </body>
    </html>
```